# Wordpress Theme is not Responsive to Updates

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a WordPress theme that's installed and has been running fine for a while. I recently needed to update the theme itself, and I did so use the built-in theme editor. Upon reloading the site, the theme changes are not presented in the markup.

Removing the index.php file from the theme or changing its name results in a blank page as expected, but removing all contents of the theme's index.php does not have a similar effect. In fact, the WordPress installation continues as if I had not made index.php blank.

I have no caching plugins installed, Varnish is not present, memcached is not in use at all, and neither is APC.

I attempted upgrading all the plugins and WordPress itself. The raw-html plugin I have installed failed to update with a fatal error about an include on line 16, but that include was not present. The update worked fine when I renamed the plugin filename though (from raw_html.php to raw_html1.php).

Comment: You might want to try posting on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ensure that you are editing the right theme - in case you have more than one.

Comment: @hakre, thanks, unfortunately we checked and we are indeed editing the right one

Comment: Is it a childtheme that you edit?

Comment: No, it's not a childtheme.  There are no parent themes or any other themes at all.

Comment: I have no clue regarding your question. What you write in your question does totally not match anything I know of. You probably overlook something, I would try a re-install.

Comment: have you checked our settings you may find a home.php page in the theme directory which is set to be the 'homepage' rather than the index.php.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the cache is the biggest issue when dealing with WordPress; Even when you don't have the cache enabled for the site. I have found that if I make the edit and look at it later, the changes have been updated.

This is not ideal for development.

Sometimes a plugin will have some type of a caching issue (even if the plugin doesn't deal with the cache) that causes the problem.